# Converting string to url, support for Hebrew language

Tags: javascript, jquery, urldecode

I'm trying to convert a string into url but I'm having issues supporting Hebrew language.

I'm using slugify function to convert string. Is there a way I can also support Hebrew languge?

Here is my function:

```
function slugify(text) {
    return text.toString().toLowerCase()
        .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
        .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
        .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
        .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
        .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
}
```